# Why are my inline-block divs not aligning?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```css
.classWrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.classInd {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF202;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 #FFF202;
  background-image: url(img/logos/logoSmall10.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.classTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: bebaslight;
  margin-bottom: 0px
}

.classInd p {
  font-family: bebaslight;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.line {
  border-top: .25px solid black;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="classWrap">
  <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:bebaslight;font-size:50px">Group Classes</h1>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Body Sculpting</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Chisel those hard-to-train areas and experience unprecedented results. Work your upper and lower and upper body, strengthen the sides of your waist and lower back and change the way you think about fitness.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Cardio Blitz</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>On busy days, the 30 minute blitz is the best way to squeeze in optimal calorie burn. We dare you to make this class your warm up!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Intro Training</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>CLearn the basics in an exciting and uplifting atmosphere. Our certified trainers will take you through all of the fundamental iRock exercises, teach you how to use the TRX Suspension Trainer, and prepare you for workouts that will change your life!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Circuit Training</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Bored of the same old workout routine? This class is for you! Blast fat, sculpt muscle, and burn up to 10 calories per minute as you move through exercises you can find only at iRock Fitness in Erie, PA.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">H.I.I.T. Abs</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Keep your heart pumping with this amazing high intensity workout that fuses serious conditioning for those all-important core muscle groups.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">MX Cardio</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">MX Strength</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Boot Camp</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>And now, the results you've been waiting for. Kick it into high gear with this high intensity circuit. Come ready to sweat!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Cardio Endurance</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Reach maximum heart rate levels as you pedal, step, jump and row your way to your fitness and weight loss goals.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding vertical-align:top to the class "classWrap" because that has fixed a similar issue and is a suggestion on other posts, but that didn't work. Some are pushed up and some are pushed down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align:top` to your `.classInd` rules.

```css
.classWrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.classInd {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF202;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 #FFF202;
  background-image: url(img/logos/logoSmall10.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.classTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: bebaslight;
  margin-bottom: 0px
}

.classInd p {
  font-family: bebaslight;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.line {
  border-top: .25px solid black;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="classWrap">
  <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:bebaslight;font-size:50px">Group Classes</h1>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Body Sculpting</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Chisel those hard-to-train areas and experience unprecedented results. Work your upper and lower and upper body, strengthen the sides of your waist and lower back and change the way you think about fitness.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Cardio Blitz</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>On busy days, the 30 minute blitz is the best way to squeeze in optimal calorie burn. We dare you to make this class your warm up!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Intro Training</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>CLearn the basics in an exciting and uplifting atmosphere. Our certified trainers will take you through all of the fundamental iRock exercises, teach you how to use the TRX Suspension Trainer, and prepare you for workouts that will change your life!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Circuit Training</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Bored of the same old workout routine? This class is for you! Blast fat, sculpt muscle, and burn up to 10 calories per minute as you move through exercises you can find only at iRock Fitness in Erie, PA.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">H.I.I.T. Abs</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Keep your heart pumping with this amazing high intensity workout that fuses serious conditioning for those all-important core muscle groups.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">MX Cardio</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">MX Strength</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Boot Camp</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>And now, the results you've been waiting for. Kick it into high gear with this high intensity circuit. Come ready to sweat!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Cardio Endurance</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Reach maximum heart rate levels as you pedal, step, jump and row your way to your fitness and weight loss goals.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't it have that by default?

Comment: @cst1992 Doesn't what have it by default? The default vertical alignment of inline elements is baseline

Comment: Sorry, `vertical-align:top` of course. Don't the `div`s have that by default?

Comment: @cst1992 Divs by default are block level elements so no, they don't have a vertical-align property as that only is applied to inline and table-cell elements

Comment: @j08691 That fixed it! I was adding "vertical-align:top;" to classWrap. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `vertical-align: top;` declaration is that you applied it to the container and not the child elements. It should be set on the `.classInd` selector.

```css
.classWrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.classInd {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF202;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 #FFF202;
  background-image: url(img/logos/logoSmall10.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.classTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: bebaslight;
  margin-bottom: 0px
}

.classInd p {
  font-family: bebaslight;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.line {
  border-top: .25px solid black;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="classWrap">
  <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:bebaslight;font-size:50px">Group Classes</h1>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Body Sculpting</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Chisel those hard-to-train areas and experience unprecedented results. Work your upper and lower and upper body, strengthen the sides of your waist and lower back and change the way you think about fitness.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Cardio Blitz</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>On busy days, the 30 minute blitz is the best way to squeeze in optimal calorie burn. We dare you to make this class your warm up!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Intro Training</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>CLearn the basics in an exciting and uplifting atmosphere. Our certified trainers will take you through all of the fundamental iRock exercises, teach you how to use the TRX Suspension Trainer, and prepare you for workouts that will change your life!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Circuit Training</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Bored of the same old workout routine? This class is for you! Blast fat, sculpt muscle, and burn up to 10 calories per minute as you move through exercises you can find only at iRock Fitness in Erie, PA.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">H.I.I.T. Abs</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Keep your heart pumping with this amazing high intensity workout that fuses serious conditioning for those all-important core muscle groups.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">MX Cardio</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">MX Strength</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Boot Camp</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>And now, the results you've been waiting for. Kick it into high gear with this high intensity circuit. Come ready to sweat!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Cardio Endurance</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Reach maximum heart rate levels as you pedal, step, jump and row your way to your fitness and weight loss goals.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that instead of defining height and width attributes for class 'classInd', define these attributes for class 'classWrap'; and for class 'classInd' you can set height and width as 100%. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding these:

```
.classInd:nth-of-type(even) {
float: right;
}

.classInd:nth-of-type(odd) {
float: left;
}
```

```css
.classWrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.classInd {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF202;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 #FFF202;
  background-image: url(img/logos/logoSmall10.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.classInd:nth-of-type(even) {
float: right;
}

.classInd:nth-of-type(odd) {
float: left;
}

.classTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: bebaslight;
  margin-bottom: 0px
}

.classInd p {
  font-family: bebaslight;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.line {
  border-top: .25px solid black;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="classWrap">
  <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:bebaslight;font-size:50px">Group Classes</h1>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Body Sculpting</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Chisel those hard-to-train areas and experience unprecedented results. Work your upper and lower and upper body, strengthen the sides of your waist and lower back and change the way you think about fitness.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Cardio Blitz</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>On busy days, the 30 minute blitz is the best way to squeeze in optimal calorie burn. We dare you to make this class your warm up!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Intro Training</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>CLearn the basics in an exciting and uplifting atmosphere. Our certified trainers will take you through all of the fundamental iRock exercises, teach you how to use the TRX Suspension Trainer, and prepare you for workouts that will change your life!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Circuit Training</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Bored of the same old workout routine? This class is for you! Blast fat, sculpt muscle, and burn up to 10 calories per minute as you move through exercises you can find only at iRock Fitness in Erie, PA.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">H.I.I.T. Abs</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Keep your heart pumping with this amazing high intensity workout that fuses serious conditioning for those all-important core muscle groups.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">MX Cardio</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">MX Strength</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Boot Camp</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>And now, the results you've been waiting for. Kick it into high gear with this high intensity circuit. Come ready to sweat!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="classInd">
    <h3 class="classTitle">Cardio Endurance</h3>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Reach maximum heart rate levels as you pedal, step, jump and row your way to your fitness and weight loss goals.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```